# How do I render an SVG inline in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have an SVG file that's part of a template located at:

```
vendor/theme/assets/icons/icon-1.svg
```

How do I render that inline in my view? `render partial: path` fails and says it can't find a partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view insert the following:

```
<%= render inline: Rails.root.join('vendor/theme/assets/icons/icon-1.svg').read %>
```

If you're going to be doing this multiple times, you may want to refactor this into a helper.

Also, think about the following:

- Are you okay with dumping third party code directly into your view?
- Is the vendor SVG file updated automatically without review?
- Are you sure the vendor SVG file will never contain malicious code?